# Regex groups, untill last occurence within group

Tags: php, regex

I am currently learning regex and it is going fine. I now want to make a checker for email addresses. Basically its all good, I just found myself stuck at one small problem which I cannot seem to solve.

I saw that you can use "lookaround" options, but I cannot get them to work.
What I want is that my group matches until the LAST `@` sign. So for example

`my-email@outlook.com` would give me back `my-email`.
`my-@-email@outlook.com` would give me back `my-@-email`.

Unfortunately my code would give me back `my-` only because I stop at the `@` sign.

Below is my reg-ex and the email addresses I check on.

I hope that someone can explain to me how I can manage it to find everything, in other words email addresses that have multiple ampersands in them too.

```
([a-zA-z0-9._\-!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~"\(\)<>:,;]+|\"[a-zA-z0-9._\-!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~"\(\)<>:,; @]+\")@([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+|\[(.*)\])\.?([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)?
```

the email adresses I check for (only 2 not working which are `john.smith@worldwideweb.123com_org` and `"John."(),:;<>@[\].Doe"@.123radio_tv)`.

```
info@kamikaze.uk
alfred@live.nl
dubai@organon.it
karel.de.koning@hetnet.nl
decock@upc.nl
jiazhe_xu@sina.cn
xfunkblasterx@yahoomail.org
super-duper-email@hotmail.com

"John..Doe"@example.com
john.smith(comment)@example.com
(comment)john.smith@example.com
john.smith@worldwideweb.123com_org
"John."(),:;<>@[\].Doe"@.123radio_tv
"much.more unusual"@example.com
other.email-with-dash@example.com
disposable.style.email.with+symbol@example.com
"()<>[]:,;@\\"!#$%&'-/=?^_`{}| ~.a"@example.org

smith@[IPv6:2001:db8::1]
jsmith@[192.168.2.1]
```

Best regards

P.S. I use https://regex101.com/ to check the regex with the provided email addys

Comment: Just add `@` after the first `([`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/sxBh8a/2).

Comment: Change `A-z` to `A-Z`. You don't need to escape `(` and `)` in a character class. You specified `_` multiple times. You can actually replace `a-zA-Z0-9_` with `\w`

Comment: @ctwheels Yeah, that will make this scary pattern a little more tamed :)

Comment: If you paste in the email list I provided, it still doesnt find email addresses with multiple @ in them :( 

@ctwheels thanks! updated my code, cleaner now :D

Comment: Also add `.` (dot) to the character range after your @

Comment: @Devbizz you do realize that `A@B@domain.com` is an invalid email right?

Answer (score 0):

I modified your regex a little bit and came up with this:

```
 ([!-Z^-~]+|\"[ -z^-~]+\")@([\w-]+|\[(.*)\])?\.?([\w-]+)?
```

The main reason why your regex failed to match some of the things you wanted to match was because some of the characters that it needed to match were not included in the regex. (`@` was not in the part of the regex before the `@`, and  `_` was not included in the domain name part of the regex)

Comment: @M4HdYaR How would that be not correct? I'm pretty sure it conforms to RFC 5322.

Comment: @JennaSloan I don't know about the RFC5322 I said that because of the question that is not pointing to RFC5322 but even in RFC5322 info@a. is not a correct email because a domain can not end with dot

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick somewhat closer to the  email regex specification (RFC5322)
you should try something like this:

raw

```
(?im)^(?=.{1,64}@)(?:("[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"@)|((?:(?:\([^)]*\)|[^\W_])(?:\.(?!\.)|[-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w]|\([^)]*\))*)?[^\W_](?:\([^)]*\))?@))(?=.{1,255}$)(?:(\[[^\[\]]+\])|((?:(?=.{1,63}\.)[^\W_][-\w]*[^\W_]*\.)+[^\W_](?:[^\W_]|-){0,22}[^\W_])|((?=.{1,63}$)[^\W_][-\w]*))$
```

stringed and delimited

```
'~(?im)^(?=.{1,64}@)(?:("[^"\\\]*(?:\\\.[^"\\\]*)*"@)|((?:(?:\([^)]*\)|[^\W_])(?:\.(?!\.)|[-!#\$%&\'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|\~\w]|\([^)]*\))*)?[^\W_](?:\([^)]*\))?@))(?=.{1,255}$)(?:(\[[^\[\]]+\])|((?:(?=.{1,63}\.)[^\W_][-\w]*[^\W_]*\.)+[^\W_](?:[^\W_]|-){0,22}[^\W_])|((?=.{1,63}$)[^\W_][-\w]*))$~'
```

https://regex101.com/r/DmX7pA/1

Explained

```
 (?im)                                     # Case insensitive
 ^                                         # BOS

                                           # Local part
 (?= .{1,64} @ )                           # 64 max chars
 (?:
      (                                         # (1 start), Quoted
           " [^"\\]* 
           (?: \\ . [^"\\]* )*
           "
           @
      )                                         # (1 end)
   |                                          # or, 
      (                                         # (2 start), Non-quoted
           (?:
                (?:                                       # comment
                     \( [^)]* \)                               # comment, or 
                  |  [^\W_]                                    # [0-9a-z] 
                )
                (?:
                     \.                                        # dot
                     (?! \. )                                  #  if not followed by dot
                  |                                          # or, 
                     [-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w]            # words or special chars
                  |                                          # or,
                     \( [^)]* \)                               # comment
                )*
           )?
           [^\W_]                                    # [0-9a-z] 
           (?: \( [^)]* \) )?                        # optional comment here
           @
      )                                         # (2 end)
 )
                                           # Domain part
 (?= .{1,255} $ )                          # 255 max chars
 (?:
      (                                         # (3 start), IP
           \[                                        # obviously, needs ip speced regex here
           [^\[\]]+ 
           \]
      )                                         # (3 end)
   |                                          # or,   
      (                                         # (4 start), Others
           (?:                                       # Labels (63 max chars each)
                (?= .{1,63} \. )
                [^\W_] [-\w]* [^\W_]*                     # [0-9a-z] [-\w]* [0-9a-z]* 
                \.
           )+
           [^\W_]                                    # [a-z0-9] [\-a-z0-9]{0,22} [a-z0-9] 
           (?: [^\W_] | - ){0,22}
           [^\W_] 
      )                                         # (4 end)
   |                                          # or,
      (                                         # (5 start), Localdomain
           (?= .{1,63} $ )
           [^\W_] [-\w]*                             # [0-9a-z] [-\w]* 
      )                                         # (5 end)
 )
 $                                         # EOS
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to accept more than one @, I think this is correct Regex for your purpose :

```
([\w@.\"\-!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~"\(\)<>:,;\[\]\\ ]+)(@)((([\w@.\"\-]*)(\.)([\w@.\"\-]+))|(\[[\w:.]+\]))
```

You can test it here with all your emails you've been provided

You can check it here https://regexr.com/4iqs1 I have tested it with all emails you said

First Group

```
([\w@.\"\-!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~"\(\)<>:,;\[\]\\ ]+)
```

is for before last @ ,

Second group is just an @

```
(@)
```

Third Group is

```
(([\w@.\"\-]*)(\.)([\w@.\"\-]+)) //It has 3 groups , first one before . second . and third is after .
```

Or

```
(\[[\w:.]+\]) //IT IS FOR IP
```